Unable to save file to device with Ionic Native HTTP
We have a mobile app developed using Angular 7 & Ionic 4. A while back we conducted a penetration test and, in order to be compliant, we changed the way files are transferred in the app. Instead of getting the file url directly through API, we receive an url of which the content type is application/octet-stream, and we use the following method to download the file and save it in device storage:
downloadFileTransfer(url, fileName) {
  const directoryPath = this.device.platform === 'Android' ? this.file.dataDirectory : this.file.documentsDirectory;
  const filePath = directoryPath + fileName;
  alert("url:" + url);
  alert("filePath:" + filePath);
  this.nativeHTTP.downloadFile(encodeURI(url), {}, {}, filePath).then(response => {
    this.appService.toastTipSuccess('success: ' + response, false);
    alert('response: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
  }).catch(err => {
    this.appService.toastTip('failure: ' + err, false);
  });
}

With this code on a real Android device, I can see the url and filePath being alerted just fine, and the response alert after downloadFile callback can be triggered just fine with response object containing the actual path where this file is supposed to be saved at. However, after checking the device storage, nothing is actually saved in the device, despite the response callback is triggered successfully.
On a side note, this is the latest attempt after many other alternatives failed: saveAs, createObjectURL, fileTransfer.download. Despite many of those approaches work in web browser, none of which worked in standalone app on real mobile devices.
Any insights or assistance would be greatly appreciated, as this issue has bothered our team for several weeks already.

This is not enough info -- https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

There may have different causes for it, even not having the permissions in the manifest can affect how you save the file, check Android Permissions
Check if you have these permissions on Manifest:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Are you using Cordova or Capacitor?
I used to develop in Cordova and had to migrate to Capacitor due to some plugins being out-of-date, and it was related to file management as well.
New versions of Android have upgraded security, so depending on where you are saving it the Android may not allow, if you have a mobile with Android < 10 available, try testing if the file is saved in your desired folder, if it does, your problem is with permissions.
Have you tried Ionic plugins such as FileSystem to manage this file?
FileSystem
Best regards, hope it may help in your issue.
